# How to output an specific csv format with open()?

Tags: python, excel, list, csv

I am trying to write a python list into a csv file by using `csv` and `os` library.

Here's what I got so far:

```
from os import path
import csv 
import os

example_list=[1,2,3,4,5]

file_path=path.relpath("path")

with open(file_path, mode='w') as f:
     list_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
     for element in example_list:
        list_writer.writerow(element)
```

However when I open it in an excel workbook the output is writed as this (where each horizontal space represent a new cell):

```
# 1  2  3  4  5
```

I've trying to get an expected output to look like this (where each vertical space represents a new cell):

```
# 1

# 2

# 3

# 4

# 5
```

How could I adjust this function in order to get desired output?

Comment: `writerow()` expects you to pass it a sequence like a list, but you are passing it a single element (a number). Try `list_writer.writerow([element])`. Note also that the documentation says to open  csv files like this: `open(file_path, mode='w', newline='')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code produces the following error:

```
_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int
```

When writing the row, you should add brackets `[]` around the `element` to build a list (which is an iterable) :

```
list_writer.writerow([element])
```

You might as well replace the `for` loop with:

```
list_writer.writerow(example_list)
```

Comment: add `open(file_path, mode='w', newline='')` to get rid of extra cells inbetween

Comment: Indeed it is necessary to add `newline=''`

Answer (score 0):

Your code gives the following error `_csv.Error: iterable expected, not int` because you need pass an iterable in `writerow()`

```
with open(path,'w',newline='') as f:
    list_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for element in example_list:
        list_writer.writerow([element])
```

Here `newline = ''` avoids adding a space of extra row

Alternate way using `writerows()`

```
with open(path,'w',newline='') as f:
    list_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    list_writer.writerows([element] for element in example_list)
```